# Pressing Enter key in Text selection within Photoshop CS6 returns to the same line

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-cs6

I am trying to create some text, however whenever I manually press enter to start the next line or the textarea naturally fills up(so that photoshop auto-handles the next line) the text cursor begins back on the start of the same line, Creating a mess, I have added a picture of this below along with a snapshot of my **Character** settings

I dont know if this is a bug or some settings which are not correct for my requirements.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line spacing [leading] is set to 0.01 pt

Try Auto, or something nearer your actual point size.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem, searching for different solutions but you may try this and I worked for me:

1. Change the language to US internation in control panel > change keyboard and other inputs > change keyboard and add US instead of UK and remove UK.
2. GO TO the character tab from window menu and set the SET THE LEADING to Auto and it worked.